# Python 3 BBS lister

Tags: python, console, ncurses

I have the following script. Which works perfectly fine with telnet (or even ztelnet), the problem is that it does not allow me to answer all of the questions with another term. Other than telnet or ztelnet. Hence I telnet to the BBS and run this script through the server, with my terminal program (igTerm) and this telnet client right here: https://github.com/seanmiddleditch/libtelnet (telnet-client). I'm trying to get it working with igTerm or telnet-client. I cannot figure this out. It has something to do with the display routines. Also, for some strange reason, it works perfectly fine from the Linux console. So, anyway, here's the script. And, yes, I know there is some "dirty code" here. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from os import system
import curses
import readline
import sys
import os
import os.path
import time
from math import *

from sites import sites

commands = ["\n\n\n add           ", " connect       ", " information   ", " help         ", " quit          "];

def pause():
     programPause = input("[16;5H[1;37mpress <[0;37mreturn[1;37m>[0;37m                [16;19H")

def execute_cmd(cmd_string):
        system("clear");
        a = system(cmd_string);

path = 'bbses/'
isExist = os.path.exists(path)
if not isExist:

  os.makedirs(path)
  print("The new directory is created!")
screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
curses.start_color()
screen.keypad( 1 )
curses.init_pair(1,curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLUE)
highlightText = curses.color_pair( 1 )
normalText = curses.A_NORMAL
max_row = 10 #max number of rows
max_row2 = 5
box = curses.newwin(0,0,5,2)

option = 0;

row_num = len( sites )
row_num2 = len( commands )

pages = str( row_num / max_row )
position = 1
page = 1
for i in range( 1, max_row + 1 ):
         if (i == position):
             box.addstr( i, 2, str( i ) + " - " + sites[ i - 1 ][0], highlightText )
         else:
             box.addstr( i, 2, str( i ) + " - " + sites[ i - 1 ][0], normalText )
         if i == row_num:
             break

pages2 = int( ceil( row_num2 / max_row2 ) )
position2 = 1
page2 = 1
box.addstr("\n\n\n\n\n")
for j in range( 1, max_row2 + 1 ):
         if (j == position2):
             box.addstr(commands[ j - 1 ], highlightText )
         else:
             box.addstr(commands[ j - 1 ], normalText )
         if j == row_num2:
             break


screen.refresh()
box.refresh()

os.system("cat bbslist.ans")

x = screen.getch()

while x != ord('q') and x != ord('Q'):  # Enter in ascii

     if x == curses.KEY_DOWN:
         if page == 1:
             if position < i:
                 position = position + 1
                 option = option + 1
             else:
                     page = page + 1
                     position = 1 + ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) )
         elif page == pages:
             if position < row_num:
                 position = position + 1
         else:
             if position < max_row + ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) ):
                 position = position + 1
             else:
                 page = page + 1
                 position = 1 + ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) )
     if x == curses.KEY_UP:
         if page == 1:
             if position > 1:
                 position = position - 1
                 option = option - 1
         else:
             if position > ( 1 + ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) ) ):

                 position = position - 1
             else:
                 page = page - 1
                 position = max_row + ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) )

     if x == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
         if page2 == 1:
             if position2 < j:
                 position2 = position2 + 1
             else:
                 if pages2 > 1:
                     page2 = page2 + 1
                     position2 = 1 + ( max_row2 * ( page2 - 1 ) )
         elif page == pages:
             if position2 < row_num2:
                 position2 = position2 + 1
         else:
             if position2 < max_row2 + ( max_row2 * ( page2 - 1 ) ):
                 position2 = position2 + 1
             else:
                 page2 = page2 + 1
                 position2 = 1 + ( max_row2 * ( page2 - 1 ) )
     if x == curses.KEY_LEFT:
         if page2 == 1:
             if position2 > 1:
                 position2 = position2 - 1
         else:
             if position2 > ( 1 + ( max_row2 * ( page2 - 1 ) ) ):

                 position2 = position2 - 1
             else:
                 page = page - 1
                 position2 = max_row2 + ( max_row2 * ( page2 - 1 ) )

     if x == ord( "\n" ) and row_num != 0 and row_num2 != 0:


         if x == 10 and position2 == 1:
                curses.endwin();
                print("[H[7;5H[1;30m+---------------------------------------------------------------+[0;37m")
                print("[8;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs name[1;30m       :                                   [1;37m  ")  
                print("[9;5H[1;30m  [1;34msysop name[1;30m    :                                   [1;37m  ")
                print("[10;5H[1;30m  [1;34mtelnet or ssh[1;30m :                                  [1;37m ")
                print("[11;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs address[1;30m   :                                   [1;37m  ")
                print("[12;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs software[1;30m  :                                   [1;37m  ")
                print("[13;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs theme[1;30m     :                                   [1;37m  ")
                print("[14;5H[1;30m  [1;34mother info[1;30m    :                                   [1;37m  ")          
                print("[15;5H[1;30m+---------------------------------------------------------------+[0;37m")

                bbsname = input("[8;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs name[1;30m      : [1;37m  ")
                type(bbsname);
                sysopname = input("[9;5H[1;30m  [1;34msysop name[1;30m    : [1;37m  ")
                type(sysopname);
                protocol = input("[10;5H[1;30m  [1;34mtelnet or ssh[1;30m : [1;37m  ")
                type(protocol)
                address = input("[11;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs address[1;30m   : [1;37m  ")
                type(address);
                software = input("[12;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs software[1;30m  : [1;37m  ")
                type(software);
                bbstheme = input("[13;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs theme[1;30m     : [1;37m  ")
                type(bbstheme);
                otherinfo = input("[14;5H[1;30m  [1;34mother info[1;30m    : [1;37m  ")
                type(otherinfo);
                print("[15;5H[1;30m+---------------------------------------------------------------+[0;37m")
                save_path = 'bbses/'
                completeName = os.path.join(save_path, address)
                saveFile = open(completeName,"a")
                file = open("sites.py", "a+")
                saveFile.write("[H[7;5H[1;30m+---------------------------------------------------------------+[0;37m")
                saveFile.write("[8;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs name[1;30m      : [1;37m  ")
                saveFile.write(bbsname)
                saveFile.write("\n")
                saveFile.write("[9;5H[1;30m  [1;34msysop name[1;30m    : [1;37m  ")
                saveFile.write(sysopname)
                saveFile.write("\n")
                saveFile.write("[10;5H[1;30m  [1;34mtelnet or ssh[1;30m : [1;37m  ")
                saveFile.write(protocol)
                saveFile.write("\n")
                saveFile.write("[11;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs address[1;30m   : [1;37m  ")
                saveFile.write(address)
                saveFile.write("\n")
                saveFile.write("[12;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs software[1;30m  : [1;37m  ")
                saveFile.write(software)
                saveFile.write("\n")
                saveFile.write("[13;5H[1;30m  [1;34mbbs theme[1;30m     : [1;37m  ")
                saveFile.write(bbstheme)
                saveFile.write("\n")
                saveFile.write("[14;5H[1;30m  [1;34mother info[1;30m    : [1;37m  ")
                saveFile.write(otherinfo)
                saveFile.write("\n")
                saveFile.write("[15;5H[1;30m+---------------------------------------------------------------+[0;37m")
                saveFile.close()
                system("perl -00pe 's/](?!.*])//s' sites.py > sites")
                system("cat sites.py | sed -e 's/];//g' > sites")
                system("mv sites sites.py")
                file = open("sites.py", "a")
                file.write(',')
                file.write('[')
                file.write('"')
                file.write(bbsname)
                file.write('", "')
                file.write(protocol)
                file.write('", "')
                file.write(address)
                file.write('"')
                file.write(']];')
                file.close()


         elif x == 10 and position2 == 2:
                i = position;
                screen.clear();
                os.system("stty raw");
                execute_cmd(sites[i - 1][1] + " " + sites[i - 1][2]);
                curses.endwin();

         if x == 10 and position2 == 3:
                i = position;
                os.system("cat " + "bbses/" + sites[i - 1][2]);
                pause()
                curses.endwin()

         if x == 10 and position2 == 4:
                system("cat bbslisthelp.ans")
                pause()
                curses.endwin()
         if x == 10 and position2 == 5:
                quit(1);


     box.erase()
     screen.border(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ')

     for i in range( 1 + ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) ), max_row + 1 + ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) ) ):
         if row_num == 0:
             box.addstr( 1, 1, "There aren't strings",  highlightText )
         else:
             if ( i + ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) ) == position + ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) ) ):
                 box.addstr( i - ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) ), 2, str( i ) + " - " + sites[ i - 1 ][0], highlightText )
             else:
                 box.addstr( i - ( max_row * ( page - 1 ) ), 2, str( i ) + " - " + sites[ i - 1 ][0], normalText )
             if i == row_num:
                 break
             box.addstr("\n\n\n\n\n")
     for j in range( 1 + ( max_row2 * ( page2 - 1 ) ), max_row2 + 1 + ( max_row2 * ( page2 - 1 ) ) ):
             if ( j + ( max_row2 * ( page2 - 1 ) ) == position2 + ( max_row2 * ( page2 - 1 ) ) ):
                 box.addstr(commands[ j - 1 ], highlightText )
             else:
                 box.addstr(commands[ j - 1 ], normalText )
             if j == row_num2:
                 break

     screen.refresh()
     box.refresh()
     os.system("cat bbslist.ans")
     x = screen.getch()

curses.endwin()
exit()
```